# Checking for exact URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having an issue checking for the URL in the pages on my site. 
This is what I have.

Checking for the exact string works well:

```
var url = location.pathname;
if ("url:contains('texas-ignition-interlock')") {
  $("body").addClass("texas-ppc-page");
}
```

But when I have page url with similar words, both classes were added to both pages.

```
var url = location.pathname;
if ("url:contains('texas-ignition-interlock-device')") {
  $("body").addClass("texas-ppc-device-page");
}
```

I also tried `indexOf`, and is didn't work do to the pages with similar names.
This is what I tried, and this works for the first example. Second example will have the first class added too.

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("texas-ignition-interlock") > -1) {
  $("body").addClass("texas-ppc-page");
}

if (window.location.href.indexOf("texas-ignition-interlock-devices") > -1) {
  $("body").addClass("texas-ppc-device-page");
}
```

Now, I can still use the `indexOf` version. I would simply target the stuff on one page using the class `.texas-ppc-page`, and on the second page I would target using both classes of `.texas-ppc-page.texas-ppc-device-page`.

Is there a better way of doing this with JS or jQuery?

Comment: why not add these classes on server?

Comment: We are on the DNN CMS. Database driven pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use split("/") to split `location.pathname` into string arrays.
`location.pathname` will be similar to `/questions/41968769/checking-for-exact-url` so by splitting this string with "/" will result into

`["", "questions", "41968769", "checking-for-exact-url"]`

now you can perform indexOf("") and it will return non -1 value if string matched exactly, like in this case if i do indexOf("url") function will return -1, and if i do indexOf("checking-for-exact-url") it will return 3.

Comment: Here is how I used your answer: var url = location.pathname.split("/");

var url1 = url.indexOf("texas-ignition-interlock");

var url2 = url.indexOf("texas-ignition-interlock-devices");

if (url1 == 2) 
{
alert("firstPage");
}

if (url2 == 2) 
{
alert("secondPage");
}
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Mohd, if you have the time check the other answer. I used your example with his together. Worked well, too.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer to examine the strings similarly to how you were, you can leverage a regex, via [.test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) as seen below with the placeholders `^` and `$`, for start and end, respectively. Otherwise, `indexOf` will match even a portion of the string. Check out the following...

```
var url = 'texas-ignition-interlock-devices';

console.log(/^texas-ignition-interlock$/.test(url));         // false
console.log(/^texas-ignition-interlock-devices$/.test(url)); // true
```

Comment: I used the first answer by Mohd. But this is great answer, too! .test was new to me. I mixed the first (accepted) answer with yours and it worked really well. Here is how I tested in firebug: 
var url = location.pathname.split("/")[2];
if(/^texas-ignition-interlock$/.test(url))
{
alert("firstPage");
}       
if(/^texas-ignition-interlock-devices$/.test(url)) 
{
alert("secondPage");
} I will upvote your answer!